# Facebook Javascript SDK - Cannot access user email

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have implemented a facebook login on my website, and authentication works fine. I can access my users name, but nothing else implying my permissions are not working correctly. I have tried a few fixes and looked around, but it seems like nothing is fixing it :/ Here is my code:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-scope="public_profile,email,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState()";>
    </div>

<script>
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                loggedIn();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //User is logged into FB, but not my app
            } else {
                //User is not logged into FB
            }
        }

        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'ID',
                cookie     : true,  
                xfbml      : true, 
                version    : 'v2.2'
                });
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });

        };
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

If anyone could lend a hand that would be great :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t see you requesting _any_ data from the API in that code… (perhaps that’s done in your `loggedIn` funtion, that you haven’t shown us?)

Answer (score 0):

i see you have a LoggedIn(); but its not declared anywhere in your code yet
so do just that can call the FB.api from there.
Heres how:

*create LoggedIn(): I recommend after your checkLoginState();

```
function LoggedIn(){
  FB.api('/me),function(response){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
 });
}
```

//i assume u have firebug running, so from here u can view the info u asked permission for.
//Note that if you're running on local host, it will ony show ur id and name

```
to get other, you would have to display them manually: like this

FB.api('/me', {locale: 'tr_TR', fields: 'id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,age_range,link,locale,email'}, function(response) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
console.log(response.name);
console.log(response.email);
```

});

Hope this is clear enough
Read up:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#steps

Comment: Also for the else part of the statusChangeCallback, i recommend FB.login(function(response){},{scope: 'public_profile,email'});